# A graph looks flatter and flatter as we zoom in

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function of class $C^1$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $Df(0) = 0$. Let

$$M = \{ (z, f(z)) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^m: z \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$$

be the graph of $f$; it is an $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. By hypothesis, the tangent plane of $M$ at the origin is the subspace $\mathbb{R}^n \times 0 \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $S$ be the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^n \times 0$.

**I would like to prove that** for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$0 < \vert x \vert < \delta \text{ and } x\in M \implies d\left( \frac{x}{\vert x \vert}, S \right) < \varepsilon.$$

Intuitively, as we zoom in at the origin, $M$ looks flatter and flatter, so eventually the directions generated by points in $M$ get closer to directions in $S$. How do I formalize this?

Comment: It is confusing to use $x$ for two very different things. I would suggest  you rename the second $x$ and relate it to the first.

Comment: You formalize this using the definition of the derivative $Df(0)$.

Comment: I think this is the idea behind blows ups and convergence of Radon measures, as in pg 8 of https://www.math.purdue.edu/~torresm/lecture-notes/geometric-measure-theory/Geometric-lecture4.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of Lee Mosher and the help of my friend Dario, this is what I got.

By contradiction, suppose that there exists a sequence $x_n = (z_n, f(z_n)) \in M$ such that $$0 < \vert x_k \vert < \frac{1}{k}$$ and $$d\left( \frac{x_k}{\vert x_k \vert}, S \right) \geq \varepsilon_0,$$

for all $k \geq 1$ and for some fixed $\varepsilon_0 > 0$.

Then, since $$\frac{x_k}{\vert x_k \vert} = \frac{(z_k, f(z_k))}{\vert (z_k,f(z_k)) \vert}$$ stays far from the subspace $\mathbb{R}^n \times 0$, there exist some $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}$ and $c > 0$ such that

$$\frac{f_i(z_k)}{\vert (z_k, f(z_k)) \vert} \geq c$$

for every $k \geq 1$. In particular, $$ \frac{f_i(z_k)}{\vert z_k \vert} \geq c$$

for all $k \geq 1$. But since $f_i(0) = 0$ and $Df_i(0) = 0$, we have

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f_i(z)}{\vert z \vert} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f_i(z) - f_i(0) - Df_i(0)(z)}{\vert z - 0 \vert} = 0,$$

a contradiction.

Comment: Why do you say $|x_k|=|z_k|+|f(z_k)|$? Are you working with the 1-norm?

Comment: Yes, I was considering this norm. But actually, it is not necessary.